# Несовместимый тип Java List<Cуперкласс> = List<Дочений>

Tags: java, spring, классы

Определил абстрактный класс:

```
@Data
public abstract class Parameter {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private boolean cumulative;

}
```

Создал на его основе дочерний:

```
@Data
public class ParameterDTO extends Parameter {

    private GroupParametersDTO group;

}
```

Пытаюсь переменной с типом `List<Parameter>` присвоить значение с типом `List<ParameterDTO>` выдает ошибку:

```
Incompatible types
Required: List<Parameter>
Found: List<ParameterDTO>
```

Я думал, что вместо суперкласса можно использовать дочерний(полиморфизм)? Или я что-то не правильно понял?

P.S. Вообще задача в следующем: метод контроллера в Spring в зависимости от переденных в запросе к серверу параметров, должен возвращать разные объекты(а точнее ResponseEntity < List < ? > >). Где вместо ? надо указать возвращаемый тип. Поэтому я хотел сделать суперкласс от него реализовать все возможные в этом методе классы и уже вместо ? указать супер класс, а возвращать уже дочерние классы.

Подскажите, как правильно решается такая задача. Когда заранее не известно, какой тип объекта должен вернуть метод контроллера?

Comment: [Ковариантность и контравариантность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так должно работать:

```
List<? extends Parameter> list = new ArrayList<ParameterDTO>()
```

Таким образом ты явно задаёшь требование что твой женерик допускает наследников. Иначе работать не будет. Джава это строго типизированный язык, поэтому с очевидностью здесь строго.